# Detect if the inputstream is deflated or not

Tags: java

I need and approach to this situation, I have read a lot and I haven't found any examples or text about it. I have one server socket which receives data from 2 clients : a) from a client that sends deflated streams. b) from a client that sends ASCII stream.

a) Receiving Deflated stream:

```
inflater = new InflaterInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(3025);
int b;
while ((b = inflater.read()) != -1) {
    bout.write(b);
}
strMessage = new String(bout.toByteArray());
```

b) Receiving from an ASCII stream :

```
bufferEnt = new char[3025];
Arrays.fill(bufferEnt,' ');
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
intLongBuffer = input.read(bufferEnt);
strMessage = new String(bufferEnt).trim();
```

On each individual situation this code works fine, and the variable `strMessage` has the correct information, but I need to identified when the stream is deflated and when is not, so I can apply the correct piece of code to each case, that's my big problem here!

Comment: do you control the clients?  if so, add a header value which indicates the type of stream data.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the client socket input stream into a `BufferedInputStream`, then wrap the buffered stream into an `InflaterInputStream`, then try to read from the inflater stream. If you get an error, then forget about the inflater stream, rewind the buffered stream, and then read from the buffered stream directly. You'll have to use the buffered stream's `mark()` and `reset()` functions to rewind the stream, and you'll probably have to experiment with `mark()` to figure out what value to pass to it. Something like the following:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
bis.mark(1024); // experiment to find the correct value here
InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(bis);
try {
    ... // Process the inflated stream
} catch (ZipException ze) {
    // It is not a ZIP stream. Try to process as text
    bis.reset();
    ... // Process the text stream
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the bytes into a buffer, then try to inflate them

```
InflaterInputStream iis = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));
...
```

if it is not a deflated stream you will get an exception, then leave the bytes as is

Comment: except that may consume bytes from the stream